# What does に do in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

> 怖い想像をするけど、僕にはこのダンジョンが下界にヒューマンと亜人{デミ・ヒューマン}を創造した神様達と同等のような
>   **存在に思えてならない。**

Why is に used here and what does it do?

Comment: There are three に's there...

Comment: made edit to bold phrase im confused about

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Correction due to the Choco san's recommendation for the correction at the comment line and with the apology to the questioner

Kindly allow me to break your sentence into the parts of the speech.

> 存在 (Noun: meaning "existence")
> **に**
> 思え (verb: meaning "to think", ア行下一段, 連用形)
> て (the conjunctive auxiliary)
> なら (verb basic なる, meaning "to become", 未然形)
> ない (auxiliary, used to be *deny* the former part of speech, 終止形)
> 。

The postpositional particle に, **[from this link](http://people.ucalgary.ca/%7Exyang/kobun/6-2-4.htm)**, would fall into the

> （七）内容・状態などを示す。「ーとして」の意。「ほうびにもらう」

Translation:

> To denote the circumstance, condition. It can be swapped by the word
> 「－として」. Example: "receive as a present"

Therefore, here, **に** can be swapped by として, thus it functions as English's *as* like you can see in the above example.

So since in your whole speech, the 存在 equals with ダンジョン and 神様, thus we can translate the broken parts of the speech as the following:

> can not help but to think XXX as the existence (with ...)

### Conclusion

Here the postpositional particle に functions as  **as** in English.

### The translation of the whole speech

> 怖い想像をするけど、僕にはこのダンジョンが下界にヒューマンと亜人を創造した神様達と同等のような 存在に思えてならない
>
> Though it might sound scary, I can not help but to think this dungeon seems to me **as** some same kind of the existence, the Gods, which created the Demi Humans underworld

Have a good luck.

Thank you.

Comment: 「思え (verb: meaning "to be thought"」>> その「思え(る)」は、受け身だとおっしゃっているのですか。「ワ行五段活用, 連用形」>> 五段活用の連用形なら「思い」じゃないですか。「思える」は自発じゃないですか。

Comment: @choco Chocho-san Thank you for your feedback. You are right. Let me amend accordingly with thank you and an apology to the questioner, as you say, it doesn't connect with 用言...

Comment: 「五段活用、連体形」＞＞＞それじゃあ「思う」になるはずでしょ。

Comment: @choco Let's see...-:) a site [link](http://koetosho.com/reading/mobile/view810200.do) says ワ行五段，and even Wiki suggests it is so [link](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%BA%94%E6%AE%B5%E6%B4%BB%E7%94%A8), but I can not think of it as ア行下一段[link](http://wikimatome.com/wiki/%E6%80%9D%E3%81%88%E3%82%8B%EF%BC%88%E6%B4%BB%E7%94%A8%E8%A1%A8%EF%BC%89), so should I take 仮定形. I will go then accordingly ( since my search suggested such a way to some degree ). KIndly allow me to thank you for your **education** ugh! -:)

Comment: @choco And if I am **still wrong** kindly let me know it and the reason why too with thank you in advance.

Comment: But it's nice to be educated ( even though to the questioner, we are **eventually** lying )......anyway, thank you for your feedback. **I'd like to have this kind of feedback when I get downvoted!**.

Comment: 「仮定形」>>> しつこいようですが、この「思える」は、「可能・自発」動詞の、「自発」の意味じゃないですか。見える、聞こえる、思える、泣ける、など・・・。ところで、ダウンボートしたの、私じゃないです。

Comment: I agreed. Thanks. I have to go into the **function** of the conjunctive particle carefully

Comment: @choco By the way, could you post your answer yours at that +50 bounties? Will you? I will be probably at least from next Tuesday I even can not look at this site since I will be so busy...

Answer (score 1):

に doesn't really have a particular meaning. It belongs together with verb 思える.
So it is always used as に思える.
When it comes to the meaning of 思えてならない, I found this older question from this site:

[What is meaning of 「〜ないように思えてなりません」?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/14090/what-is-meaning-of-%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%AB%E6%80%9D%E3%81%88%E3%81%A6%E3%81%AA%E3%82%8A%E3%81%BE%E3%81%9B%E3%82%93)